# Use selenium pull the link from an href which is an attribute of a class element that has a random class name?

Tags: python, selenium, class, href, element

Here is the element. Be aware I slimmed it down, there is much more in the `</div>`:

```
<a class="123abc456def" download="" href="https://www.downloadme.com/1jk43jkls.txt role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><div></div></a>
```

The class name is a random string of characters so I cant use that as an identifier.
I want to grab the href link. How can I do that with selenium in python?

I tried the following but they did not work:

```
link_elm = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//download[@href]")
link_elm = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used the xpath, searched for an `a` class element, and then searched for if it contained part of the url. Then I pulled the href link with `get_attribute`

```
link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class and contains(@href, 'downloadme')]").get_attribute("href")
```